# swift 5 Как создать простейшую анимацию(маленькие кубики разлетаются в стороны от слова Поздравляю!)

Tags: swift, xcode

Весь код:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @objc func WordsCardValue(_ sender: UIButton) {
        buttonWords2.isHidden = false
        buttonWords.isHidden = true
        countOfSuccesfulWords += 1
    }
    
    @objc func WordsCard(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //Относится ли отправитель к кнопка коллекций
        if buttonsMassive.contains(sender) {
            senderIndex = buttonsMassive.firstIndex(of: sender)!
            //Задача данных переменным
            countOfWordsForDictionaryCheck = countOfWordsForDictionary[senderIndex]
            namesCollectionForCardsLabel.text = namesForButtonCollection[senderIndex]
        }
        senderIndexCount = 0
        senderIndexCountMin = 0
        
        
        //Объявление главного словаря
        if checkFirst {
            if senderIndex == 0 {
                countOfWordsForDictionaryCheckMin = 0
                countOfWordsForDictionaryCheckMax = countOfWordsForDictionaryCheck*2
            } else {
                for i in countOfWordsForDictionary {
                    if senderIndex > senderIndexCount {
                        senderIndexCount += 1
                        senderIndexCountMin += i
                    } else {
                        countOfWordsForDictionaryCheckMin = senderIndexCountMin * 2
                        countOfWordsForDictionaryCheckMax = countOfWordsForDictionaryCheckMin + countOfWordsForDictionary[senderIndex]*2
                        break
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
        if buttonsMassive.isEmpty != true {
            wordCardToKeyButton()
            countOfSuccesfulWordsLabel.text = String(countOfSuccesfulWords)
            countOfSuccesfulWordsLabel.isHidden = false
            namesCollectionForCardsLabel.isHidden = false
        } else {
            buttonMassiveEmpty()
        }
        
    }
    
    
    func wordCardToKeyButton() {
        buttonWords2.isHidden = true
        if checkFirst {
            for i in dictionaryCollections[countOfWordsForDictionaryCheckMin..<countOfWordsForDictionaryCheckMax] {
                if check {
                    dictionaryKey.append(i)
                    dictionaryCollections.remove(at: dictionaryCollections.firstIndex(of: i)!)
                    check = false
                } else {
                    dictionaryValue.append(i)
                    dictionaryCollections.remove(at: dictionaryCollections.firstIndex(of: i)!)
                    check = true
                }
            }
            checkFirst = false
            
            //На случай ошибки при вводе данных
            if dictionaryKey.count < dictionaryValue.count {
                countOfWordsMax = dictionaryKey.count
            }
            if dictionaryValue.count < dictionaryKey.count {
                countOfWordsMax = dictionaryValue.count
            }
            if dictionaryKey.count == dictionaryValue.count {
                countOfWordsMax = dictionaryKey.count
            }
            //
            
        }
        
        buttonWords.isHidden = false
        //Создать копию buttonMassive
        for i in buttonsMassive {
            i.isHidden = true
        }
        if dictionaryKey.isEmpty {
            wordCardEnd()
        } else {
            buttonWords.setTitle(dictionaryKey[0], for: .normal)
            dictionaryKey.remove(at: 0)
            if dictionaryValue.isEmpty {
                wordCardEnd()
            } else {
                buttonWords2.setTitle(dictionaryValue[0], for: .normal)
                dictionaryValue.remove(at: 0)
                
            }
        
        
        
    }
}
 
    func wordCardEnd() {
        checkFirst = true
        congratulationsLabel.isHidden = false
        buttonsMassive.remove(at: senderIndex)
        countOfWordsForDictionary.remove(at: senderIndex)
        namesForButtonCollection.remove(at: senderIndex)
        countOfSuccesfulWordsLabel.isHidden = true
        countOfSuccesfulWords = 0
        buttonWords.isHidden = true
        buttonWords2.isHidden = true
        namesCollectionForCardsLabel.isHidden = true
        congratulationsLabel.isHidden = true
        for i in buttonsMassive {
            i.isHidden = false
            //Сделать функцию, чтобы правильно принимало размеры
        }
        if buttonsMassive.isEmpty {
            buttonMassiveEmpty()
        }
    }
    
    /*@objc func massLeave(_ sender: UIButton) {
        countOfSuccesfulWordsCopy = countOfSuccesfulWords
        countOfSuccesfulWordsLabel.isHidden = true
        countOfSuccesfulWords = 0
        buttonWords.isHidden = true
        buttonWords2.isHidden = true
        for i in buttonsMassive {
            i.isHidden = false
            //Сделать функцию, чтобы правильно принимало размеры
        }
    }*/

    func buttonMassiveEmpty() {
        checkFirst = true
        countOfSuccesfulWordsLabel.isHidden = true
        namesCollectionForCardsLabel.isHidden = true
        buttonWords2.isHidden = true
        randomElementForKeyAndValue = Int.random(in: 0..<dictionaryCollectionsCopy.count)
        if randomElementForKeyAndValue % 2 == 0 {
            buttonWords.setTitle(dictionaryCollectionsCopy[randomElementForKeyAndValue], for: .normal)
            buttonWords2.setTitle(dictionaryCollectionsCopy[randomElementForKeyAndValue+1], for: .normal)
        } else {
            buttonWords.setTitle(dictionaryCollectionsCopy[randomElementForKeyAndValue-1], for: .normal)
            buttonWords2.setTitle(dictionaryCollectionsCopy[randomElementForKeyAndValue], for: .normal)
        }
        buttonWords.isHidden = false
    }
    
    var namesForButtonCollection : [String] = ["fruits", "city", "clock"]
    var countOfWordsForDictionary : [Int] = [4, 3, 2]
    
    
    var check = true
    var buttonNamesCheck = 0
    
    var countOfWordsForDictionaryCheck = 0
    var countOfWordsForDictionaryCheckMin = 0
    var countOfWordsForDictionaryCheckMax = 0
    
    var randomElementForKeyAndValue = 0
    
    var countOfSuccesfulWords = 0
    var countOfSuccesfulWordsCopy = 0
    var countOfWordsMax = 0
    
    var senderIndexCount = 0
    var senderIndexCountMin = 0
    
    var checkFirst = true
    
    
    var buttonWords = UIButton()
    var buttonWords2 = UIButton()
    var senderIndex = 0
    var leaveButton = UIButton()
    
    
    let buttonsColumnSize : Int = Int(round(UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 - 30))
    let buttonsColumnPlace2 : Int = Int(round(UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 + 10))
    var buttonWordsSize : Int = Int(round(UIScreen.main.bounds.width)) - Int(round(UIScreen.main.bounds.width/10))
    
    
    var buttonsMassive = [UIButton]()
    var buttonsMassiveCopy = [UIButton]()
    
    
    var namesCollectionForCardsLabel = UILabel()
    var countOfSuccesfulWordsLabel = UILabel()
    var congratulationsLabel = UILabel()
    //Переделать на анимацию

    
    var buttonCount = true
    
    
    var dictionaryCollections : [String] = ["Apple", "Яблоко", "Grape", "Виноград", "Garnet", "Гранат", "Pear", "Груша", "Market", "Рынок", "House", "Дом", "Flat", "Квартира", "Ten", "Десять", "Clock", "Часы"]
    var dictionaryCollectionsCopy : [String] = []
    
    
    var dictionaryKey : [String] = []
    var dictionaryValue : [String] = []
    var dictionarySave = 0
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dictionaryCollectionsCopy = dictionaryCollections
        buttonWords.frame.size = CGSize(width: buttonWordsSize, height: buttonWordsSize)
        buttonWords.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(roundf(Float(buttonsColumnSize / 10)))
        buttonWords.center = self.view.center
        buttonWords.backgroundColor = .placeholderText
        buttonWords.setTitleColor(.darkText, for: .normal)
        buttonWords.addTarget(self, action: #selector(WordsCardValue(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(buttonWords)
        buttonWords.isHidden = true
        
        
        buttonWords2.frame.size = CGSize(width: buttonWordsSize, height: buttonWordsSize)
        buttonWords2.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(roundf(Float(buttonsColumnSize / 10)))
        buttonWords2.center = self.view.center
        buttonWords2.backgroundColor = .placeholderText
        buttonWords2.setTitleColor(.darkText, for: .normal)
        buttonWords2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(WordsCard(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(buttonWords2)
        buttonWords2.isHidden = true
        
        /*leaveButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "hit.png"), for: .normal)
        leaveButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(massLeave(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)
        leaveButton.frame = CGRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: buttonWordsSize, height: buttonWordsSize)
        view.addSubview(leaveButton)*/

        namesCollectionForCardsLabel.font = UIFont(name: "systemFont", size: round(UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 20))
        namesCollectionForCardsLabel.backgroundColor = .clear
        namesCollectionForCardsLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 30, width: 100, height: 100)
        namesCollectionForCardsLabel.center.x = self.view.center.x
        
        countOfSuccesfulWordsLabel.font = UIFont(name: "systemFont", size: round(UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 20))
        countOfSuccesfulWordsLabel.backgroundColor = .clear
        countOfSuccesfulWordsLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 400, width: 100, height: 100)
        
        congratulationsLabel.font = UIFont(name: "systemFont", size: round(UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 10))
        congratulationsLabel.backgroundColor = .clear
        congratulationsLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 30, width: 200, height: 300)
        congratulationsLabel.center.x = self.view.center.x
        congratulationsLabel.text = "Congratulations!"
        
        createButtons()
        view.addSubview(namesCollectionForCardsLabel)
        view.addSubview(countOfSuccesfulWordsLabel)
        view.addSubview(congratulationsLabel)
        
        congratulationsLabel.isHidden = true
    }
    
    private func createButtons() {
        buttonNamesCheck = 0
        
        
        
        
        var y = 50
        
        
        for i in 0..<namesForButtonCollection.count {
            

            var buttonCollectionFrame = CGRect(x: 20, y: y, width: buttonsColumnSize, height: buttonsColumnSize)
            var buttonCollectionFrame2 = CGRect(x: buttonsColumnPlace2, y: y, width: buttonsColumnSize, height: buttonsColumnSize)
            let button = UIButton(type: .system)
            if buttonCount {
                button.frame = buttonCollectionFrame
                buttonCount = false
            } else {
                button.frame = buttonCollectionFrame2
                buttonCount = true
                y += buttonsColumnSize + 20
            }
            button.backgroundColor = .gray
            button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
            
            button.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(roundf(Float(buttonsColumnSize / 10)))
            
            
            
            
            view.addSubview(button)
            buttonsMassive.append(button)
            buttonsMassiveCopy.append(button)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(WordsCard(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)
            
            }

        for i in buttonsMassive[0..<namesForButtonCollection.count] {
            i.setTitle(namesForButtonCollection[buttonNamesCheck], for: .normal)
            buttonNamesCheck += 1
        }
        
    }
            
        
        
    }
```

Не обязательно взаимодействовать с кодом, можно просто пример

Comment: Рассмотрите использование SpriteKit как вариант https://dou.ua/lenta/articles/spritekit-for-swift-animation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример простой анимации на основе частиц SpriteKit, основанный на [данной статье](https://dou.ua/lenta/articles/spritekit-for-swift-animation/)

Создаем сцену и файл для работы с частицами, можно выбрать разные шаблоны при создании и поиграться с их настройками

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настраиваем сториборд

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Связываем все в коде

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var congratulationsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var particlesView: SKView!
    
    var scene: SKScene? {
        let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "MyScene")
        scene?.backgroundColor = .clear
        return scene
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        congratulationsLabel.isHidden = true
        
        particlesView.backgroundColor = .clear
        particlesView.allowsTransparency = true
        // фикс для избавления от мерцания при загрузке
        let emptyScene = SKScene()
        emptyScene.backgroundColor = .clear
        particlesView.presentScene(emptyScene)
    }
    
    func showCongratulations() {
        congratulationsLabel.isHidden = false
        particlesView.presentScene(scene)
    }
    
    @IBAction func runParticlesAnimationButtonTouchUpInside(_ sender: UIButton) {
        showCongratulations()
    }
    
}
```

...

**Профит**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]